Pac4j IdentityProvider Metadata as string
I am currently using pac4j to implement the SAML flow. To set the Identity Provider metadata we have an option to pass it as a file or resource or classpath.
Due to few security constraints, few of the paths are not openly accessible. So we save the entire Identity Provider metadata file content into the DB.
Is there a simpler way to load the Metadata content as a string into the SAML2Configuration()?
One way that I could think of was to create a Custom SAML2MetadataResolver and pass that to the configuration.
But wanted to check if there is any other simpler way to do this.

You need to create your own mapping from your database data to the SAML2Configuration component.

You mean to create my custom mapping and set it using SAML2MetadataResolver

No, I mean to override the SAML2Configuration by a new DbSAML2Configuration and override its internalInit method.

May be I am understanding this wrong. But my issue is I do not have an publicly accessible url to setIdentityProviderMetadataResourceUrl. I have the xml content stored in my DB.
I did not find anything related to this in the  internalInit method of SAML2Configuration. But found initIdentityProviderMetadataResolver in the SAML2Client clientInit method.
Confused what to override in the internalInit method of SAML2Configuration. Am I understanding this wrong ?

Using pac4j version 4.5.7

SAML2Configuration cannot be built from metadata, but metadata are generated from the configuration and can be stored in database.
